# Get rid of wordpress editor auto tags on specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

I have a problem when i add some code to wordpress editor it automatically add some HTML like `span`, `<br/>` and `<p>` it also remove my `<div>` tag or remove its classes is there any plugin or hook which i can implement on specific post or page, i am not finding any solution which implement rest on my website.
Like here is the code which i want to add in wordpress editor.

```html
<div class="home_book">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/someimage.png" alt="" class="center-block" />
  </a>
  <p>6th grade Valerie Marzden’s school year is pretty normal. But real life problems turn this clever girl into a biz-whiz kid overnight. Can she pull her family and friends out of impending disaster?</p>
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-md custom_color_btn text-center" href="#" role="button">Order Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't tried it yet here is a solution Disable Wpautop plugin http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/disable-wpautop/

Comment: Are you adding the code under the `text` tab, or the `html` tab in your Wordpress editor? Just switching.. note the difference.

Comment: @TimHallman `text` tab

Comment: Where is `HTML` tab there are only two `visual` and `text`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... the `text` tab should indeed handle html input, the `visual` tab being the one which will insert <tags>. If you're pasting in the `text` tab and Wordpress is still adding tags, is it possible you have some type of code editor plugin installed? or something creating an issue with your post editor? Perhaps try pasting the same code into another fresh install and see if the results are different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using the WordPress editor, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/ just use shortcode `[raw] Your HTML code [/raw]`